# Data frame modification for Machine Learning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am creating an Recommendation Machine Learning modal and above are the data set,

*name* is name of the song, *song* is the mp3 file, *likes*  are the song has got,

```
   id        name         song   likes   
0    1        eeee    song.mp3      70     
1    2        aaaa    song.mp3      59    
2    3    any song    song.mp3       7    
3    6   australia    song.mp3      99   
4    7       qwert    song.mp3       0   
5    9      summer    song.mp3      10
```

Here the *song_id* is the id of the song in above data set and *performer* is the id of the artist who has performed in the song, one song can have more than 1 artist as you can see song with id 1 has 3 artist id's associated with it named 9,10,11

```
    song_id  performer
0         1          9
1         1         10
2         1         11
3         2          9
4         2         10
5         2         11
6         2          5
7         3          9
8         3         10
9         6          5
10        6          9
11        6         10
12        6         11
13        6         16
14        7          5
15        7          9
16        7         10
17        7         11
18        7         16
19        9         16
20        9         17
```

How can I join both datasets as one dataset? How can I display this OneToMany relation (1 song - many performers) in my dataframe? as you can see there are 6 songs and 21 song and performer relation.

Comment: This is a standard `pandas` question about how to join/merge two dataframes, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` (or K-means) - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if merge works -

```
df2.merge(df1)
```

[image: click for result image]

Comment: Please do not post code or data as images - copy & paste them as text instead.